# Excel not reporting a circular error

Tags: excel

There's lots of questions about Excel reporting circular calculation errors when none exist, but I have the opposite problem: I have a sheet that my Excel says is fine, but when I open it on another machine it reports a rather obvious circular error formula.

Excel 2010 Pro Plus. Error checking is turned on in Options. When I try it manually by clicking Formula->Error Checking, it reports "error checking is complete" with no problems reported.

Anyone see this before?

Comment: It is. And someone else found it and emailed me...

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a much less obvious than it should be:

```
1) File->Options
2) Formulas tab
3) Turn off "Enable Iterative Calculation"
```

It's perfectly obvious in retrospect, but I looked at that option a dozen times...